# Shell script to ls and execute command on ls result

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a list of folders inside a folder in ubuntu.
ie.
Under /mnt/source/customcode/files/brands/

```
root@a919794ec280:/mnt/source/customcode/files/brands# ls -la
total 236
drwxrwxrwx 19 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:26 .
drwxrwxrwx  8 1002 1003   4096 Dec 27 22:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 aem
drwxrwxr-x  3 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 apple
drwxrwxr-x  3 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 cool
drwxr-xr-x  3 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 doll
drwxr-xr-x  3 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 ent
drwxr-xr-x  3 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 f1
drwxr-xr-x  3 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 google
drwxrwxrwx  3 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 h1
drwxrwxr-x  3 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 iq
drwxr-xr-x  3 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 king
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 link
drwxrwxrwx  3 1002 root 155648 Jan  3 09:22 nobrand
drwxrwxr-x  3 1002 1003  12288 Jan  3 09:22 pepperfry
drwxrwxrwx  2 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 pepsi
drwxrwxr-x  2 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 rock
drwxrwxrwx  2 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 star9
drwxrwxr-x  2 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 vicks
----- 100+ -----
```

Like above, I have folders like "a1", "cola", "link" and etc. (more then 100 folders)

In side those each folders there will be a folder named "data_aug" and "data_aug" folder do contain files inside.

```
root@a919794ec280:/mnt/source/customcode/files/brands/apple# ls -la
total 1988
drwxrwxr-x  3 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 .
drwxrwxrwx 19 1002 root   4096 Jan  3 09:26 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  17465 Dec 29 23:28 0DPA0C3.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003   3836 Dec 31 00:55 130418131111-apple-store-santa-monica.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  48616 Dec 31 00:52 15146774227434507677123475441338.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003   9107 Dec 31 00:52 15146774615326659565665852728294.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  28005 Dec 29 23:28 3D-Apple-Logo-Wallpapers.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  75855 Dec 29 23:28 3D-Apple-Logo.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  27403 Dec 29 23:28 3d_apple_logo___wallpaper_by_techflashdesigns-d4fbc7p.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  38420 Dec 29 23:28 AX62GjL.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003   6025 Dec 29 23:28 Apple-Logo-2016 (1).jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003 929419 Dec 29 23:28 Apple-Logo-Png-Download.png
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  35742 Dec 29 23:28 apple-logo-2016.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  15301 Dec 29 23:28 apple-logo-3d-model-max-obj-fbx-3dm-ige-igs-iges.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  42514 Dec 29 23:28 apple-logo-clipart-2.jpeg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003 152183 Dec 29 23:28 apple-logo-clouds.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003   6117 Dec 31 00:55 apple1.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003 349787 Dec 29 23:28 apple_ipad_logo.png
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  54167 Dec 29 23:28 b5c4d6c9-3.jpg
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jan  3 09:22 data_aug
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  32918 Dec 29 23:28 large.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  48972 Dec 29 23:28 medium.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003   3609 Dec 29 23:28 th (1).jpeg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  30392 Dec 29 23:28 th (2).jpeg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003   3222 Dec 29 23:28 th.jpeg
-rw-r--r--  1 1002 1003  22544 Dec 29 23:28 u5TAcBk.jpg

root@a919794ec280:/mnt/source/customcode/files/brands/apple/data_aug# ls -la
total 4356
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  12288 Jan  3 09:41 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 1002 1003   4096 Jan  3 09:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10450 Jan  3 09:40 apple_0_1.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5599 Jan  3 09:40 apple_0_1019.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3225 Jan  3 09:40 apple_0_1075.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10283 Jan  3 09:40 apple_0_1100.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13923 Jan  3 09:41 apple_0_1119.jpeg
```

Now...

I need a script to be placed in "/mnt/source/customcode/"

Want to run the script from "/mnt/source/customcode/" as my script dependent files are can only be executed from "/mnt/source/customcode/"to achieve bellow.

- Delete the folder "data_aug" and the data inside "data_aug"
  recursively from all the 100 folders.
- Then from the "/mnt/source/customcode/" location I should execute a
  special script which, it will refer those 100 folders. like example
  below.

Code...

```
python -m scripts.augmentation_keras --image_dir=files/brands/apple --target_dir=files/brands/apple/data_aug --save_prefix=apple

python -m scripts.augmentation_keras --image_dir=files/brands/a1 --target_dir=files/brands/a1/data_aug --save_prefix=a1
```

like above for all the 100 folders.  The number of folders 100 will grow more in future.

How can I do it dynamically instead of writing simple script with hundreds of lines (static deletion and execution)!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
for d in /home/user/data/*
do
rm -rf $d/content/*
python -m scripts.augmentation_keras --image_dir=$d --
 target_dir=$d/content --save_prefix=$(basename $d)
done
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to insure that the file in `$d` is a `directory` before pulling the trigger on `python....`? Like `[ -d "$d" ] && python ....`? It's not clear from the question that can be assumed, even though it states "*I have a list of folders inside a folder in ubuntu. ex..*"

Comment: I am modifying my question for better understanding.

Comment: @Peter:  --image_dir=$d is working good but for target_dir= <the script is taking as 'files/brands/apple/data_aug/files/brands/apple_0_0.jpeg.  Means it is adding the "do" path again.

Comment: @Sagar post your script that you have so far.

Comment: for d in files/brands/*
do
python -m scripts.augmentation_keras --image_dir=$d --target_dir=$d/data_aug --save_prefix=$d
done

Comment: My mistake missed out "$(basename $d)" in prefex.  Thanks, Peter.